# c# winforms How to get DataGridViewCells in a list by correct order

Tags: c#, winforms, list, datagridview

```
List<string> a = new List<string> {};    
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dgvC.SelectedCells)
{
a.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
}
string line = string.Join(",", a.ToArray());
MessageBox.Show(line);
```

MyCellsValues are 1 2 3 4 5
Why is my string 5 4 3 2 1
What a stupid behaviour!

Comment: Do you need that List<string> after the foreach loop or you use it only to get the `line` string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
a.Insert(0, cell.Value.ToString());
```

or use

```
a.Reverse();
string line = string.Join(",", a.ToArray());
```